# Find a missing element in a sorted list

Tags: c, binary-search

I've made a program to find the missing element (if there's one) in a sequential list:

> **Program criteria:**
>
> Returns `-1` if a list is sequential, otherwise the missing element in a non-sequential list is returned.
>
> To perform binary search, we need a key to half the problem size. Here the key is to find the distance between the index (`low`, `high`) and their corresponding values.
>
> Compilation procedure:
>
> ```
> gcc -Wall -g testList.c -o testList
>
> ./testList
> ```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
int bSearch(int array[], int low, int high){

  int mid = (low + high) / 2;

  if(high == low + 1){
    if(array[high] > array[low] +1){
      return array[low] +1;
    }else{
      return -1;
    }
  }

  if(array[mid] - array[low] == mid - low){
    return bSearch(array, mid, high);
  }else if(array[mid] -  array[low] > mid - low){
    return bSearch(array, low, mid);
  }else{
    return -1;
  }
}


int main(void){

  int array [] = {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 30};
  int upperBound = (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))-1;
  printf("%d\n", bSearch(array, 0,  upperBound));
  return 0;
}
```

My questions:

1. Why does removing the `else{}` case cause the compiler to give a warning for it?
2. Can the base case look more elegant?
3. For code elegance and optimization, can this code be improved?

Comment: I don't think I can help you with an answer as I'm not fluent in C but I can tell you that *removing the `else{}`* will cause error because not all method paths return value.

Comment: @denis Can you add datastructures tag?

Comment: @overexchange: No, we've destroyed that tag, so it shouldn't be added anymore.

Comment: "removing the else{} case" --> Which `else` are you asking about?  Posting sample code without the `else` would help clarify the question.

Comment: @chux `else` working with `else if`

Comment: Are you asking why `if(array[mid] ...){ return ...;  } /* else */  if(array[mid] - ...){ return ...; }else{  return -1; }`cause the compiler to give a warning?

Comment: @chux am asking if I remove else, why compiler is giving warning? I think you are placing seed in my brain

Answer (score 3):

> Why does removing the `else{}` case cause the compiler to give a warning for it?

The compiler will indeed issue a warning if a value-returning function doesn't return a value for every path.  Ignoring this warning could then cause undefined behavior.

If you intend for `bSearch()` to return `-1` on failure, then you can put just one `return -1;` at the very end of the function and remove the `else`s that return `-1`.

Comment: My point is, What is the chance that you get to very end? Do you think there is a chance? Give me a case where we can get to very end

Comment: @overexchange: What I'm saying is that it's a possible alternative for having those `else`s.  Otherwise, you can keep what you already have.

Comment: Even if there is no way to get to the very end, you can't prove that to the compiler.